# Can't pass event to addEventListener: closure issue

Tags: javascript, events, closures, addeventlistener

This one's driving me crazy... I have a loop which adds an event listener to an SVG object. The object is, for the sake of argument, a small circle, and I have to add mouseover and mouseout events for each of the 10 circles.

My first problem is the standard closure-scope thing - because all the listeners are added in the same loop, they all see the same invalid value of the loop variable. I can fix this, I think, but the second problem is that I have to pass 'event' to the listeners, and I can't find any way to fix both these issues simultaneously.

I've tried various versions of this:

```
for(month = 0; month < nMonths; month++) {
   ...
   shape.addEventListener(
     "mouseover", 
     (function(event, index) { popup_on(event, foo, index); })(event, month),
     false);
   group.appendChild(shape);
}
```

This particular version gives me 'event is not defined'. `popup_on` is the real handler, and must get `event` and the current value of `month`. Any idea how I should be doing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The event will be passed to your function **automatically**—just make it the first argument to the function you pass to `addEventListener`.  Also, false is the default value for the capture parameter.

```
(function() {
    var i = month;
    shape.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) { popup_on(e, foo, i); });
})();
```

Also, are you ok with `foo` being closed over in your event callback?  If not, you could do the same thing with it

```
(function() {
    var i = month;
    var f = foo;
    shape.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) { popup_on(e, f, i); });
})();
```

And if all these local variables are getting annoying, you can make them parameters to possibly make things a bit more tidy

```
(function(i, f) {
    shape.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) { popup_on(e, f, i); });
})(month, foo);
```

Comment: Sorry to be so dumb, but where do I actually put this function? 'shape' is created in a loop, maybe 10 or 20 times over, and each new instance of 'shape' (from 'createElementNS') has to have a handler attached to it. So there doesn't seem to be anywhere where I can put this anonymous function where the current 'shape' is in context? Given this, don't I have to put everything in the 'addEventListener' call itself? Which, I think, leaves the problem of how I can get both 'e' and 'month' in as params...?

Comment: @user785194 I think the code I put above will work fine.  Each time shape is re-created, just put the code above in there to add the event listener to that particular instance.