# Send event when calling anonymous addEventListener function, then remove it

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I can add an event listener and sent it the event like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8714513/1252748):

```
(function(){
 document.getElementById("submitBtn").addEventListener("click", function(event){
    pD(event);
  }, false);
}());

function pD(event){
   event.preventDefault();  
}
```

Since I can't pass the `event` parameter to the function I want called on the click, is there any way I can get the `event` so I can use a named function so I can remove the listener? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5660165/1252748) seems related, but it doesn't seem concerned with passing a parameter like event. Or is there a way to remove all listeners from an element?

Comment: Why not just do `"click", pD, false)`? now you can unbind it with `pD` and the event type.

Comment: @KevinB And then what does `function pD()` look like? Doesn't it need to be sent the `event` still? Thanks much.

Comment: That happends automagically !

Comment: @thomas it looks just like it does now.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, have a look at on() and off() ?

Comment: Okay. So I can always reference `event` without specifically passing it? `<input type="button" onClick="show()" /> ... function show(event){ console.log(event);}`;

Comment: @thomas "*Okay. So I can always reference event without specifically passing it?*" Yes, if it's an event handler and you are using a modern browser. That specific case though with the `onclick=""` is very different, that's NOT passing an event handler, that's just executing a function. In that case, you WOULD have to pass `event`.

Comment: @KevinB Right. I don't know why I typed it like that, differently than the function was assigned in my question. Thanks for clearing this up.

Comment: @adeneo I am and I will. Thanks much!

Comment: @KevinB, yes, my fail

Comment: @adeneo I feel like you should submit that as an answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery, why not use .on and .off? Example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/justincook/7JZcD/)

```
<a class="test">Test Click</a>

<script>
$(".test").on("click", function(event){
  console.log(event);
  $(".test").off().text('click handler now off');
});
</script>
```