# How to removeEventListener that was added using closure?

Tags: javascript, closures, dom-events, addeventlistener

This is basically a followup question to this: [Can't pass event to addEventListener: closure issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714472/cant-pass-event-to-addeventlistener-closure-issue).

I have read almost every related question and can't find the answer to this.

The function below is executed within a loop where the parameters are pulled from an array of data.
With this function I am able to pass different/new parameters to each instance of an event listener. The outerfunction allows for the values of the parameters to be encapsulated within closure so that the actual values are available, not just references to the holders. Additionally, the passeventfunction passes the event to the responsefunction. Finally, the responsefunction has all the appropriate info in order to respond to the click event. This works great.
The problem is, I can't figure out how to remove the event listener at a later time. I have tried everything that I can think of. Please help. How can I: removeEventListener ?

```
(function outerfunction(i, f) {
     elementname.addEventListener("click", function passeventfunction(e) { 
         responsefunction(e, f, i); });})(parameter1, parameter2);
```

also, if someone could help clear up what is happening here. Is this a closure within a closure? Is there a danger of leaving a memory leak or something?

Comment: You need to save a reference to `passeventfunction` somewhere so that you can pass that into `removeEventListener`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to keep references to your listeners:

```
var listeners = {};
for(/* ... */) {
   (function outerfunction(i, f) {
        var listener = function(e) { 
            responsefunction(e, f, i); 
        }
        elementname.addEventListener("click", listener);
        listeners[elementname.id] = listener; // use something meaningful 
                                              // as your keys
   })(parameter1, parameter2);
}

// Removing the listener later:
elementname.removeEventListener("click", listeners[elementname.id]);
```

Comment: I'd recommend a Map instead of a generic object because you can use the element itself as the key in the Map whereas the generic object only accepts strings as keys.

Comment: Yes, that would be a nice improvement. Note that I wrote this back in 2013, when Maps weren't a thing yet.

Comment: If one of you bfavaretto or @bpossolo could provide an answer to this specific question using a Map that models the accepted answer, it would be a great addition to this Q/A (and I would be forever grateful!). I understand enough to know it's what I'd like to do, and have read about it, but cannot find an example to this question that helps me through the details.