# How to NOOP removeEventListener disabling all javascript

Tags: javascript, promise

I want to ensure that a piece of code executes, and sticks around to execute.

My thought process is, disable all event listeners, start a recursive promise chain with a setTimeout inside, reinstate the event listeners.

Something like:

```
((_do)=>{
    // some additional things based on suggestion from @Yury
    var NOOP = () => {}
    var origEvents = [EventTarget.prototype.removeEventListener, 
    Function.prototype.call, Function.prototype.bind, 
    Function.prototype.apply]
    var copyEvents = origEvents.slice();
    origEvents.map((c)=>{ c = NOOP });

    window.recurse = function recurse(){
        function this_here(_do) {
            if (_do) {
                var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
                for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
                    all[i].__nativeREL__ = all[i].removeEventListener
                    all[i].removeEventListener = () => {}
                    // add this back later
                }    
            }
        }

        function test() {
            var some_test = true
            if (some_test){
                return Promise.resolve('done with stuff')    
            } else {
                return Promise.resolve()
            }
        }

        function delay(ms) {  
              return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                  setTimeout(() => {
                      resolve()
                  }, ms);
              });
        }

        return Promise.resolve(r)
                        .then(this_here)
                        .then(delay)
                        .then(test)
                        .then(recurse)
                        .catch(e => {console.error(e)})
    }
    recurse()
})(true)
```

How can I ensure that this code executes, and continues executing?

Basically stopping everything on the page, until the piece of code says otherwise?

side thought: maybe I could add some sort of middleware on the event bubbling?

Related:

- [How to removeEventListener that was added using closure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19774202/how-to-removeeventlistener-that-was-added-using-closure)

Comment: Seems like a lot of work (especially iterating over the entire DOM) when you could just set the `body` to `display:none` or slap a "loading" spinner on it. Besides that, I'm pretty sure `do` is a reserved keyword.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan True https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Reserved_keywords_as_of_ECMAScript_2015

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan aye thanks for the `do` catch. I know I completely agree, but what about the javascript that get's added outside of the body tag?

Comment: If you want to noop `removeEventListener` you could do `EventTarget.prototype.removeEventListener = () => {}` but how would this help to "disable all javascript"?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Any JavaScript in any `<script>` element will be parsed and executed as it is discovered in the HTML. Hiding the `body` means that code can't make visible DOM changes before you want them, and the user can't interact with anything, thus obviating the need to remove event listeners.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I was just trying to say that `<script>` tags can exist outside of the `<html></html>` and is still valid. Like all the stuff on the queue will fire off events even if the body is removed, it only removes a subset of the possible places where events can happen. I am working on a weird use case using the ICAP protocol.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko perhaps "disable" isn't the right word here. I was thinking about how item's get into the event loop. and maybe it's a bit naive, but then i thought hey it can't be as simple as disabling events can it?

Comment: "... a piece of code executes, and sticks around to execute" ... is what we call a function isn't it? The jump from that to disabling/reinstating event listeners is not at all clear.