# Remove a window event Listener from the handler function

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I have a function `begin` that declares an addEventListener with a handler function `check`. Now when a particular condition is satisfied inside `check`, I want to remove the eventListener.

My code:

```
function begin(data){
    //code
    window.addEventListener('keyUp', check(data));
}

function check(data){
    return function check1(event){
        //code
        if(condition) window.removeEventListener('keyUp', check(data));
    }
}
```

Everything is working fine but it isn't removing the `EventListener`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to removeEventListener that was added using closure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19774202/how-to-removeeventlistener-that-was-added-using-closure)

Comment: Psst, it's removeEventListener(), not removeListener() :) Plus: read the answears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make the `check(data)` response function unique for the handler, like passing it to a variable. Otherwise you will get another function every time you call `check(data)` and you try to remove the wrong one.

```
var handler;

function begin(data) {
    handler = check(data);
    window.addEventListener('keyUp', handler);
}

function check(data) {
    return function check1(event) {
        if(condition) {
            window.removeEventListener('keyUp', handler);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be removeEventListener?

Comment: Of course, thank you. Just copied the code from the question ... @Metaphox

Comment: You do not need a global variable in this particular example. You could just use `check1` instead of `handler`, because it will be always different for each call of `check`.

Comment: ooh.. I get it! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The `check1` will be always a different function for each call of `check` so you can remove itself using `window.removeEventListener('keyup', check1 )`:

```
function begin(data) {
  //code
  window.addEventListener('keyup', check(data));
}

function check(data) {
  return function check1(event) {
    if(condition) {
       window.removeEventListener('keyup', check1 );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow. This one worked too. Now I'm confused because eisbehr's answer also worked. Which one should i mark as the best answer? :D

Comment: I vote for this one, but the other fella has less points, so you can feed the other one, too :D

Comment: yours is better because it uses whats already available ^_^ take a +1

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out your handler function is not `check` so you cant remove it. The handler function is the function check returns.

To better understand whats going on you can type.

```
check().prototype.constructor.name // 'check'
check.prototype.constructor.name   // 'check1'
```